# Deleting rows with MySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, delete-row, sql-delete

I have two tables, one for job deadlines, one for describe a job. Each job can take a status and some statuses means the jobs' deadlines must be deleted from the other table.

I can easily `SELECT` the jobs/deadlines that meets my criteria with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `deadline`
LEFT JOIN `job` ON deadline.job_id = job.job_id
WHERE `status` = 'szamlazva'
OR `status` = 'szamlazhato'
OR `status` = 'fizetve'
OR `status` = 'szallitva'
OR `status` = 'storno'
```

(`status` belongs to `job` table not `deadline`)

But when I'd like to delete these rows from `deadline`, MySQL throws an error. My query is:

```
DELETE FROM `deadline`
LEFT JOIN `job`
ON deadline.job_id = job.job_id
WHERE `status` = 'szamlazva'
OR `status` = 'szamlazhato'
OR `status` = 'fizetve'
OR `status` = 'szallitva'
OR `status` = 'storno'
```

MySQL error says nothing:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `job` ON deadline.job_id = job.job_id WHERE `status` = 'szaml' at line 1

How can I turn my `SELECT` into a working `DELETE` query?

Answer (score 438, accepted):

You simply need to specify on which tables to apply the `DELETE`.

Delete only the `deadline` rows:

```
DELETE `deadline` FROM `deadline` LEFT JOIN `job` ....
```

Delete the `deadline` and `job` rows:

```
DELETE `deadline`, `job` FROM `deadline` LEFT JOIN `job` ....
```

Delete only the `job` rows:

```
DELETE `job` FROM `deadline` LEFT JOIN `job` ....
```

Comment: With "AS" I had to use the alias in my clause to make it work for my purpose (delete orphans): DELETE t1
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN t2 AS t2
ON t1.uid = t2.result
WHERE t2.result IS NULL

Comment: Interestingly, my PHPMyAdmin 4.5.1 syntax checker wouldn't accept anything between `DELETE` and `FROM`, but the query ran ok anyway when I pressed Go.

Comment: @clayRay PHPMyAdmin is pretty frought with edge-case problems.

Answer (score 51):

If you are using "table as", then specify it to delete.

In the example i delete all table_1 rows which are do not exists in table_2.

```
DELETE t1 FROM `table_1` t1 LEFT JOIN `table_2` t2 ON t1.`id` = t2.`id` WHERE t2.`id` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

This script worked for me:

```
DELETE t
FROM table t
INNER JOIN join_table jt ON t.fk_column = jt.id
WHERE jt.comdition_column…;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
DELETE `deadline`
FROM `deadline`
INNER JOIN `job` ON `deadline`.`job_id` = `job`.`id`
WHERE `job`.`id` = 123
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM deadline where ID IN (
    SELECT d.ID FROM `deadline` d LEFT JOIN `job` ON deadline.job_id = job.job_id WHERE `status` =  'szamlazva' OR `status` = 'szamlazhato' OR `status` = 'fizetve' OR `status` = 'szallitva' OR `status` = 'storno');
```

I am not sure if that kind of sub query works in MySQL, but try it. I am assuming you have an ID column in your deadline table.

Comment: OP still needs to specify what to `DELETE` to make the query unambiguous. Using `In` with subqueries makes everything a lot slower. It's best avoided.

Comment: No table mentioned between `DELETE` and `FROM` .

Answer (score 2):

MySQL allows you to use the INNER JOIN clause in the DELETE statement to delete rows from a table and the matching rows in another table.

For example, to delete rows from both T1 and T2 tables that meet a specified condition, you use the following statement:

```
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition;
```

Notice that you put table names T1 and T2 between the DELETE and FROM keywords. If you omit T1 table, the DELETE statement only deletes rows in T2 table. Similarly, if you omitT2 table, the DELETE statement will delete only rows in T1 table.

Hope this help.