# mySQL DELETE from one table using field from natural joining with another table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
DELETE FROM `takes` WHERE ID, course_ID IN
(SELECT ID, course_ID FROM `takes` natural join `student`
where name = 'Jane' and course_ID='BIOL101')
```

From the `takes` table, I am trying to drop all Janes who are enrolled in BIOL101.

The SELECT gives me the correct set of IDs and course_IDs, and I am just trying to DELETE that from the `takes` table. Having trouble figuring out the proper syntax.

phpMyAdmin gives me the error: "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'takes' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: `WHERE ID, course_ID IN (..)` doesn't that look *wrong*?

Comment: Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4192849/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/2763245/2864740 , and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html for "DELETE .. JOIN" syntax - boo to using IN for join logic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider not [ab]using `IN`, but rather use a proper [`DELETE..JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) which MySQL does support.

```
DELETE takes
FROM takes
JOIN student s
  -- The relation/schema is unclear; adapt as required
  -- but MAKE SURE A RELATION IS ESTABLISHED!
  ON s.student_id = takes.student_id
WHERE s.name = 'Jane'
  AND takes.course_ID = 'BIOL101'
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192849/2864740).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  DELETE FROM `takes` WHERE (ID, course_ID) IN
  (select * FROM(
 (SELECT ID, course_ID FROM `takes` natural join `student`
  where name = 'Jane' and course_ID='BIOL101')t )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM `takes` 
WHERE `ID` IN 
(
    SELECT ID FROM `takes`
    NATURAL JOIN `student`
    WHERE `name` = 'Jane` AND `course_ID` = 'BOIL101'
)
```