# Delete rows from multiple tables with a left join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I searched a lot online and I can't figure out how do to do my simple task.

I want to delete all those row that im selecting with this following query.

```
`SELECT * FROM `session` s
LEFT JOIN `pages` p ON (s.Id = p.VisitorSessionId)
LEFT JOIN `product_views`ps ON (s.Id = ps.VisitorSessionId)
WHERE s.`JSEnabled` = 0
```

And I tried to delete those row by using

```
DELETE FROM `session` s
LEFT JOIN `pages` p ON (s.Id = p.VisitorSessionId)
LEFT JOIN `product_views`ps ON (s.Id = ps.VisitorSessionId)
WHERE s.`JSEnabled` = 0
```

I tried to do something similar to this post answer
[Deleting rows with MySQL LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763206/deleting-rows-with-mysql-left-join)
But its not working.

How can i make this query without having to do a loop in my application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to delete only from one table then it could be done as

```
DELETE s FROM `session` s
LEFT JOIN `pages` p ON (s.Id = p.VisitorSessionId)
LEFT JOIN `product_views`ps ON (s.Id = ps.VisitorSessionId)
WHERE s.`JSEnabled` = 0
```

For deleting from multiple tables with join it would be as

```
DELETE s,p,ps FROM `session` s
LEFT JOIN `pages` p ON (s.Id = p.VisitorSessionId)
LEFT JOIN `product_views`ps ON (s.Id = ps.VisitorSessionId)
WHERE s.`JSEnabled` = 0
```

Comment: No yeah, I need to delete all tables rows that match the session table row selected

Comment: Oh wow,..  I had it then, But i was using tables names instead,.

Well thanks for the fast answer!  I have to wait to mark this answer as accepted lol..

Comment: An OUTER JOIN in a DELETE clause is a rare event. Maybe there is a reason!

Comment: @Strawberry Why are you saying that ? What is the reason ?