# How to delete rows in MYSQL where a column doesn't contain certain data

Tags: mysql, database

A database I am in charge of fixing got filled with spam. There is a table called **url** in the database.  There is a column called **alias**.  There is **2,000 correct alias rows** that should be there and the other **100,000+ are spam**.  I have a comma separated list of all the correct values that should be there.  An example value in Alias would be z6j6h and they are all 5 letters/numbers.  How can I delete every row that does not contain a value in the good list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE
  FROM (table)
 WHERE alias NOT IN ('ASDFG', 'ABCDE')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find_in_set()` function:

```
delete from mytable
where find_in_set(alias, 'abcde,ghijk,etc') = 0
```

Comment: Hi this seems backwards.  This would delete abcde,ghijk,etc.  I need it to delete everything but abcde,ghijk,etc.

Comment: @Bohemian - the comma-separated list has all the good aliases, which shouldn't be deleted. The condition should be `find_in_set(alias, 'blah,foo,etc') = 0`.

Comment: @edg missed that, thanks - I've adopted your suggestion into my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not at a console-apologies for terseness!  One way would be to put your correct values in another table and run an outer join on the main table and the correct-values table.  That will give you all the rows of the main table, with NULLs flagging the spam.  Then you delete rows having those nulls.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214674/2877364 for a join example and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763245/2877364 for deleting.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from url
where alias not in (
  'my',
  'list',
  'of',
  'good',
  'aliases'
);
```