# Why is this MySQL Delete command getting an error?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this MYSQL command:

```
DELETE FROM hotel h
LEFT JOIN user_hotel uh ON h.hotel_id = uh.hotel_id
WHERE uh.user_hotel_id IS NULL
```

It is returning this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'h LEFT JOIN user_hotel uh ON h.hotel_id = uh.hotel_id WHERE
>   uh.user_hotel_id I' at line 1

The command seems self-explanatory, so not sure what I'm getting wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the table name which you want to delete like

```
DELETE h FROM hotel h
LEFT JOIN user_hotel uh ON h.hotel_id = uh.hotel_id
WHERE uh.user_hotel_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing table_name those you want to delete

```
DELETE h FROM hotel h
LEFT JOIN user_hotel uh ON h.hotel_id = uh.hotel_id
WHERE uh.user_hotel_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I thought it may be something like that, but I was checking out this article and it just had it as the way I wrote it. Do you know why they don't mention it the way you are? http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/delete.php

Comment: in this article they are performing action on single table ,while in your case you have two table .hence you have to mention table_name that you want to delete :-)

Comment: Thanks Jordan that makes sense

Comment: @zeckdude:- When you are deleting the records using JOIN then you need to mention the table name from which you want to delete else it will create an ambiguity for the MYSQL engine. In the link which you provided they are using a single table hence you dont need to specify the name of the table explicitly as it is implictly understood by the engine.

Comment: Mark this as accept answer ..so it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE h FROM hotel h
LEFT JOIN user_hotel uh ON h.hotel_id = uh.hotel_id
WHERE uh.user_hotel_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

# what to delete is missing . Delete from table work only if no join

```
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for clarifying why it wont delete with the join if I don't specify what to delete!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify table name on which you are going to apply DELETE in case of JOIN.
See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763206/deleting-rows-with-mysql-left-join).

You need to write MySQl query like below:

```
DELETE h,uh FROM hotel h
LEFT JOIN user_hotel uh ON h.hotel_id = uh.hotel_id
WHERE uh.user_hotel_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
DELETE column_name(which you want to delete) FROM hotel h
LEFT JOIN user_hotel uh ON h.hotel_id = uh.hotel_id
WHERE uh.user_hotel_id IS NULL
```