# what's wrong with this delete statement

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have this sql statement to delete some rows:

```
DELETE 
FROM
  `user_group_membership` g
  INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.user_id = g.user_id
WHERE
  u.`user_id` NOT IN (?, ?, ?)
  AND g.group_id IN (9, 6)
  AND u.`lifetime_supporter` = 0
  AND u.supporter_type = 'special'
```

I get an SQL error of "SQL ERROR SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'g INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.user_id = g.user_id WHERE u.`user_id` NOT IN ( ?,?,?"

Not entirely sure what's wrong here, could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763206/deleting-rows-with-mysql-left-join?rq=1

Comment: Ah thanks, had to do "DELETE g FROM" to make it clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify from which table you need to Delete the record.
If you want to delete from Table user_group_membership, you need to specify table  after DELETE Command like below:

```
DELETE g
FROM
  `user_group_membership` g
  INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.user_id = g.user_id
WHERE
  u.`user_id` NOT IN (?, ?, ?)
  AND g.group_id IN (9, 6)
  AND u.`lifetime_supporter` = 0
  AND u.supporter_type = 'special'
```