# Error when deleting from multiple mysql table Unknown table 'table1' in MULTI DELETE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I ran this query in mysql but it showed an error `Unknown table 'table1' in MULTI DELETE`. Can anyone guide me on what is wrong please?

```
DELETE table1, table2,table3, table4
from table1 as t1 
left join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.tid 
left join table3 as t3
on t1.id = t3.tid
left jointable4 as t4 
on t1.id = t4.tid 
where t1.id = 77
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting rows with MySQL LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763206/deleting-rows-with-mysql-left-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you use aliases in multiple delete then you must specify the aliases after `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3, t4
from table1 as t1 
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.tid 
left join table3 as t3 on t1.id = t3.tid
left join table4 as t4 on t1.id = t4.tid 
where t1.id = 77
```